# Is it safe to assume that leading underscores are ignored when using the dot syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, underscores

Quick question. All of the courses that teach objective C that I have participated in always prefix their instance variables with an underscore. They also explain that when using the dot syntax that you dont have to include the leading underscore of instance variables when accessing them. They never explicitly said that using the dot syntax with Objective C will always ignore leading underscores, and thats my question. Will dot syntax ALWAYS ignore leading underscores in Objective C?

To clear up confusion, if I have a class `Item` and it has an instance variable called `*_itemName`, I can later (in main) set that variable by using dot-syntax and ignoring the leading underscore with `Item.itemName = something.`

I would've thought when I first started working on Obj-C that I would've had to set `_itemName` INCLUDING the underscore with `Item._itemName = something`.

So is it the case that dot syntax ignores leading underscores?

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? Direct ivar access and property access are two different, though related, things. The ivar and the property have different names.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I edited my post to better explain my question

Answer (score 1):

"Dot syntax" isn't actually a shortcut for accessing *instance variables*, but for accessing *properties**.

Properties *might* save/load their data from an instance variable, but they could also derive their data from a multitude of other variables. They're intended as an abstraction & layer of indirection.

* Technically you can use it for any method that looks like a property's method... but that's usually *strongly* discouraged. Don't do that!

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I was trying to ask. While I understand it is discouraged and I don't plan on doing it, I was just confused as to whether or not dot is "supposed" to ignore leading underscores like it does.

Comment: Your asterisk is a little unclear. Most methods that actually look like properties conceptually are properties. I think what you mean is that the getter syntax can be used for any zero-parameter method — even if it isn't a getter — and the setter syntax can be used for any one-parameter method, even if it isn't a setter. It's fine to use it for things that aren't declared properties as long as they are de facto properties.

Comment: @user1806716: I don't think you understood Kitsune's answer. It **isn't** ignoring any underscore. It's calling the accessor for the `itemName` property, which is what accesses the `_itemName` instance variable. No underscore is ignored anywhere.